# how to move home in ubuntu

Tags: partitioning, mount, users, home-directory

I got a Ubuntu 15 VM and I am adding a second virtual disk for the home partition.

I moved the old home to home.old. and have mounted the new home on the new disk. and the mount is successful. But when I go see home, I don't see the directory for my test user. the directory for test is still under home.old.

I also tried to create a new test user, test2 but neither home nor home.old shows me the directory test2.

```
test2@test-virtual-machine:/$ cd /home
test2@test-virtual-machine:/home$ ls
lost+found
test2@test-virtual-machine:/home$ cd ..
test2@test-virtual-machine:/$ ls /home.old/
test
test2@test-virtual-machine:/$
```

What's going on here?

Thanks

EDIT: 
as per request

```
test@test-virtual-machine:/home$ cd ~
bash: cd: /home/test: No such file or directory
test@test-virtual-machine:/home$ pwd
/home
test@test-virtual-machine:/home$ ls
aquota.user  lost+found
test@test-virtual-machine:/home$
```

Comment: Run 'cd ~; pwd; ls' and tell me the results please

Comment: hi, the results are posted to the question

Comment: Hmm weird but I meant as test2

Comment: still the same result: `bash: cd: /home/test2: No such file or directory`

Comment: What happens if you run 'mkdir /home/test'?

Comment: I can do it successfully as root and sudo with test, test2 isn't sudoer so that naturally fails

Comment: Does it work properly then? After adding it manually?

Comment: Never mind I saw that an answer was already made :)

Comment: yes, it works at intended, but that's pretty weird right? I would expect that at least test2's dir should automatically be created under the new home.

Comment: What are the permissions on /home? If this fixes it can I at least post on my own?

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  4096 Jun 16 23:31 home`

Comment: That's really weird mine are the same... hmm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
sudo cp -pR /home.old/test /home
cd
ll
```

Make sure the files listed (except for `..`) all have your user name. For example:

```
drwx------  3 yourusername yourusername   4096 Jan  1  1970 .gnome/
```

---

It's a bit confusing, but to add a new user, don't use `useradd`. `man useradd` says:

> useradd is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian, administrators should usually use adduser(8) instead.

Instead, first remove the user you created with `useradd` by using `deluser`:

```
sudo deluser --remove-home test2
```

Then, add a user with `adduser`:

```
sudo adduser test2
```

Follow the prompts, and you'll have a new user properly created.

Comment: it works, but how come the new user's directory aren't created or placed under the new home?

Comment: How did you add the user?

Comment: useradd then set password

Comment: OK, I've added a section about that.

Comment: @Grammargeek, `..` in that directory listing is `/home`, which is owned by `root`. However, `.` in that directory listing is `/home/test`, which should be owned by `test`.

Comment: I tried the adduser, `sudo adduser test3' and get this result 'sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified 
`

Comment: @D.Zou, are you running that inside a terminal on that machine or from `ssh` on another machine or something else?